# facebook login in develpment mode on localhost

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I got a job interview which requires me to create a web app with Facebook login. I created the app and everything is working fine, But I got problems...
I noticed that my login page works only with my facebook account because it is in developer mode - this is a big problem for me because my interviewer wont be able to use this feature.
Is threre any way to allow all users test my app without going public with it (I dont have privacy policy , urls, etc...)
for now I am thinking to create a fake test account and send by mail but it is stupid Idia...

Comment: Either invite the interviewer to become a tester of your app (requires that they registered as a developer on the Facebook platform), or create an actual test user, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-users Fake accounts aren’t recommendable, those get blocked when discovered.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Facebook app Dashboard and under Roles tab try adding your client profile as Administrators/Developers/Testers your client has to accept the provided role and now it should work as expected.